# "Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent" при старте сессии

Tags: php

Возникает ошибка:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at Z:\home\bemulima\www\index.php:2) in Z:\home\bemulima\www\index.php on line 17
```

а на 17 строке:

```
 session_start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже где-то до вызова функции идет вывод информации

```
session_start(); // должна вызываться в самом начале скрипта/страницы
```

Comment: <?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Данные два файла нужно включать только в случае определения INCLUDE_CHECK


session_name('tzLogin');
// Запуск сессии

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Устанавливаем время жизни куки 2 недели

session_start(); // еще выше поднять?

Comment: @bemulima, попробуйте использовать UTF-8(Без BOM). В одном из файлов (текущем, connect.php или function.php присутсвует сивол который выводится на страницу или вывод. Т.е. вывода может и не быть, но присутствует Unicode символ, используемый для индикации порядка байтов. Он вам всё губит. `session_start` указывается **до** любого вывода. Смотрите файлы, ищите вывод или кодировку.

Comment: Проверил, у всех UTF-8 без BOM.

Comment: @bemulima, ищите какой-либо вывод. Других вариантов нет.